# XBee Wi-Fi - decoding UDP packets of sampled data

Tags: xbee

I just bought an XBee Wi-Fi S6B. (I was expecting it to be similar to the [WiFly](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/wifi/software/wifly.html) that can easily post sampled [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) data to a webpage.) I am going to hook two temperature sensors to the analog inputs. Note - there are no Arduinos in this project.

I have configured the XBee to send [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) packets to my computer on port 3054 (0xBEE) - I can see them using [Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

**My question**: Is there any existing software out there for Linux or the Raspberry Pi that can receive these packets and decode them? I'd rather not have to re-invent the wheel. I've searched extensively, but everything I found was for API mode with an arduino attached. I'm interested in just running the XBee with the two temperature sensors.

Many of the search results I've seen are for talking to *another* XBee connected to my computer via a serial port. I'd rather not buy an extra XBee, because my computer is already on the same network.

Comment: It is also entirely possible that I simply don't have my terminology right yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small program I just created to listen for XBEE UDP packets. It listens currently for one temperature sensor, but is easily configurable to add on other sensors.

https://github.com/bseeger/XBEE_Listener